# Xamarin.Forms Image in ListView DataTemplate not appearing in WinPhone 8.1

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

Image XAML component doesn't work when placed in the listview data template in Xamarin.Forms for Windows Phone 8.1. Image appear fine in Android and iOS.

```
  <ListView x:Name="recipeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Tweets}" HasUnevenRows="true">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell> 
       <ViewCell.View>                  
        <StackLayout>
          <Image Source="{Binding ImageURI"} />
        </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

where ImageURI = "http://some-image-off-the-web.jpg"

*Update* In UWP the text doesn't even appear! Forget the image, the actual text is invisible. I can see that that each list item is populated using the Visual Studio Live Property Explorer, there is definitely text to display in each list item, its just invisible. I remove the Grid the label is and it works fine. Image still not shown. Do ViewCells not work well in windows?

Comment: How does you `ImageUri` look like? Are you loading images from assets or from the web?

Comment: They are from the web (see edit), lets just say when I take the Image out of the ListView DataTemplate it renders fine. OR if I use an ImageCell instead of a ViewCell again the images render fine. :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your Image Source in the StackLayout.

```
    <StackLayout>
      <Image Source="{Binding ImageURI"} />
    </StackLayout>
```

The quotation marks are not aligned.